# Execute batch file in foreground

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, node-webkit

Having a nodejs app (node-webkit in fact), how can I launch a batch file in foreground in whatever folder it is in?

So far I have succeeded in running the batch file with the following:

`require('child_process').spawn(pathToBat, [], dirOfBat)`

However this is run in the background.
**Edit for clarifaction**: in foreground means, that a separate window is opened to display all output generated by the batch file.

I've tried all sorts of variations with `child_process.exec` and with passing the batch file to both `start` and `cmd` but I can't seem to make it work. Any hints?

Comment: What do you mean by running in foreground?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren: In foreground I mean that a window with the output of the `cmd` process running the batch file is displayed on screen. I can see the process showing up in the task manager, but the window is not created.

Comment: That's a total different thing ... I'll Edit my answer

Comment: To pipe stdout of the child process to stdout of the node app would be an easy task (as @AvnerSolomon answered), but I dunno if it's possible to run a command in a new window. If there's a terminal command that runs the command in a new window you would use that, but afaik node can't do that by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge you can't. But you can pipe the steams
child.stdout and child.stdin
to
process.stdout and process.stdin

**Edit**

After the explanations from your comment I think you're looking for exec or execFile.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('explorer'); exec('notepad'); exec('start cmd');
```

Something like this?

Comment: Indeed, something like that, but if I `exec('cmd')`, I don't get a window.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem was that I tried something like `exec('start', ['cmd', args, for, cmd])` whereas this does the job: `exec('start cmd args for cmd')`.

Comment: exec, unlike spawn , has no args. The firs parameter is the whole command while the second are env options and third is the callback

Comment: Hi there, maybe i am being stupid but when you have spawned a new cmd window with exec('start cmd'); how do you execute commands on it? For example from your description i thought you would just be able to do something like this: exec('start cmd dir'); To execute the dir command in this new window but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that cause exec runs a process while dir is just an internal command command you have to ran cmd and sent "dir" at the stdin process. Never tried